# Cant add a variable to the database correctly

Tags: android

Lets say i wanted to add another variable to the database can anybody tell me how to do it because i keep on trying for hours but always getting errors at the end of it . Thanx 
Ive tried to make a new create method with a new get method but that did not work aswell

Comment: Try isolating the error, narrow it down to a specific call and/or exception. "Please debug this long wall of code for me" is not how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the DB schema, you need to increment the DB version so the onUpdate method will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up an example android project that uses SQLite. Browsing through one of those should answer many of your questions.